# Increase transfer speed from iPhone X to Macbook Pro

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, video, lightning

I've shot several videos in 4k 60 fps from the iPhone X and when I wanted to transfer them to my Macbook Pro using the lightning to USB-A cable, it took multiple hours where the videos were approximately 60 GBs. My Macbook Pro is a mid 2015 model with USB 3 ports. How can I increase the transfer speed?

Comment: Is the cable an Apple official brand cable? I ask because off brands sometimes aren’t the same. While 60GB is a lot, “multiple hours” isn’t an exact amount of time. Please be more specific. 2 hours for 60GB is reasonable.

Comment: yeah its an official cable and yes it was around 2hours I guess. I dont consider it reasonable when boths ends are ssds... my internet is like 4x faster.. (500mbits)

Comment: Well speed of transfers is relying on many variables. Background processes, disk writes and read speeds, cable, etc. In the end I don’t think much can be done to speed it up much faster aside from using a better cable other than USB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use air drop. It's a lot faster than the cable and work perfectly fine.